# C++ Async function not launched asynchronously

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to launch a function asynchronously but it gets launched synchronously.

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

std::future<int> setPromise()
{
    auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<int>>();
    auto future = promise->get_future();
    auto asyncFn = [&]() {
      cout << "Async started ...\n";
      for(int i=0; i<100000; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<10000; j++) {}
      promise->set_value(400);
      fprintf(stderr, "Async ended ...\n");
    };
    std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFn);
    return future;
}

int main()
{
   std::future<int> result = setPromise();
   cout << "Asynchronously launched \n";
   int ret = result.get();
   cout << ret << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Compiled it with the following command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread promise.cpp -o promise
```

I expect the lambda function to get called asynchronously and while the loop is running in asynchronous thread i expect the logs from the main. But i see the function never gets launched asynchronously and always the lambda gets completed and only then we get the next statements in main to be executed

What i expect

```
Async started ...
Asynchronously launched
Async ended ...
```

What i get is

```
Async started ...
Async ended ...
Asynchronously launched
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling below line

```
std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFn);
```

is created temporary `future` object, and its destructor ends only if task started by `async` finishes. So at the end of scope of `setPromise` function its execution is blocked until job - `asyncFn` ends.

You can read about behaviour future destrcutor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future) and what happens when shared state of future is not ready.

Comment: +1, indeed the implicit future generated by `std::async` is not used at all, while you set the result of a different future from the lambda itself. A better approach would be `auto asyncFn = [&]() { ... return 400; }; return std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFn);` which would work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is running asynchronously just completes quickly.

To confirm for sure, you need to make your logging race condition free.

Something like this (just the idea):

```
std::future<int> setPromise()
{
    std::atomic_flag canGo = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

    auto asyncFn = [&] {
        while (!canGo);
        log("Async started ..."); // also use thread-safe logging
        ...
    }

    std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFn);
    log("letting it go...");
    canGo.test_and_set();

    ...
}
```

Note also, that `iostream` is not thread safe, so you better use a thread safe logger when experimenting.